# How can I log out a user from the server in Meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my Meteor.js application, I want to let the administrator be able to forcibly log out users.

The use case is that my application is serving end-users, and the service is open whenever a super-user is logged in. If a super-user has forgotten to explicitly log out, the service will seem to be open for the end-users. If an administrator sees this, he/she should be able to forcibly log out the logged in user, and such render the service closed for the end-users.

Is this possible with Meteor.js? If so, how? Are there better/other approaches to this use case?

EDIT: Added some examples of remote logout I have tried, to clarify for @Akshat.

EXAMPLE 1(which does not work as I want):

In a logout method:

```
if (user.profile.role === ROLES.ADMIN) {
            Meteor
                .users
                .update({
                    _id: options.userId
                }, 
                { 
                    $set: { 
                        'services.resume.loginTokens' : [] 
                }});
        } else {
            throw new Meteor.Error(403, "You are not allowed to access this.");
        }
```

In my application.js:

```
var lastUserId;
Deps.autorun(function () {
    if(Meteor.user()) {
        if (Meteor.user().profile && Meteor.user().profile.firstName) {
            console.log("USER LOGGED IN");
            console.log("LENGTH LOGINTOKENS", 
                    Meteor
                        .user()
                        .services
                        .resume
                        .loginTokens.length); // This is always 1
            lastUserId = Meteor.user()._id;

            if (Meteor.user().services.resume.loginTokens.length === 0) {
                // This never fires, and thus the client does not know until
                // manually refreshed. Of course I could keep a forceLogOut-variable
                // as done in the next example.
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    } else {
        console.log("SOMETHING CHANGED IN METEOR.USER");
        if (lastUserId) {
            console.log("THE USER IS LOGGED OUT");
            Meteor.call('userLoggedOut',
            {
                userId: lastUserId
            });
            lastUserId = null;
        }
    }
});
```

EXAMPLE 2(this works as I want, when using only forceLogOut together with Meteor.logout() on the client side.):

In a logout method:

```
if (user.profile.role === ROLES.ADMIN) {
            Meteor
                .users
                .update({
                    _id: options.userId
                }, 
                { 
                    $set: { 
                        'services.resume.loginTokens' : [],
                        'profile.forceLogOut': true
                }});
        } else {
            throw new Meteor.Error(403, "You are not allowed to access this.");
        }
```

In my application.js:

```
var lastUserId;
Deps.autorun(function () {
    if(Meteor.user()) {
        if (Meteor.user().profile && Meteor.user().profile.firstName) {
            console.log("USER LOGGED IN");
            console.log("LENGTH LOGINTOKENS", 
                    Meteor
                        .user()
                        .services
                        .resume
                        .loginTokens.length); // This is always 1
            lastUserId = Meteor.user()._id;

            if (Meteor.user().profile.forceLogOut) {
                // Small example 1:
                // When logintokens have been set to [], and forceLogOut
                // is true, we need to reload the window to show the user
                // he is logged out.
                window.location.reload();
                // END Small example 1.

                // Small example 2:
                // When already keeping this variable, I might as well just use
                // this variable for logging the user out, and no resetting of
                // loginTokens are needed, or reloading the browser window.
                // This seems to me as the best way.
                console.log("FORCING LOGOUT");
                Meteor.logout();
                // END Small example 2.

                // And finally resetting the variable
                Meteor.call('resetForceLogOut',
                    {
                        userId: Meteor.user()._id
                    });
           }
        }
    } else {
        console.log("SOMETHING CHANGED IN METEOR.USER");
        if (lastUserId) {
            console.log("THE USER IS LOGGED OUT");
            Meteor.call('userLoggedOut',
            {
                userId: lastUserId
            });
            lastUserId = null;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to delete all the `loginTokens` from the database. It will do it for all users with this query. You can customize the selector if you want to log out a smaller subset of users or exclude the current user.

```
Meteor.users.update({}, {$set : { "services.resume.loginTokens" : [] }}, {multi:true});
```

A couple of things:

- This will log out all users including the current logged in user.
- It only works on the server side

Comment: I will try this at once! Thank you for the quick response. Is this documented anywhere, btw?

Comment: I dont think it is documented but Meteor uses the values inside `loginTokens` to identify users who are logged in. So without them the users are logged off since everything is reactive

Comment: Sometimes it works like a charm, and the user view is rerendered and the user is redirected to the login page. But other times the user still is able to move around inside the "restricted area". I have to do a refresh for the user to see that it's logged out. How can I fix this?

Comment: @user2602152 In the restricted area you need to check whether the user is logged in reactively and if not show a message. If you've done this have a look at the javascript console to see if there are any errors that may be preventing the template changing.

Comment: I am using Deps.autorun to check Meteor.user(), but it doesn't seem to fire when I log out a user this way. Not seeing any errors in the console, but if I refresh the page, I get the message and are redirected to login.

Comment: Do you have any proposal for my last comment? Meteor.user() does not fire when logging out a user this way. How would I reactively go about checking if the user is logged in any other way?

Comment: @user2602152 could you put up the code you're using to check the user is logged in? It also takes a bit of time to log the user out i hope you've taken this into account its not latency compensated.

Comment: what about setting a variable on the profile called profile.forceLogOut, and then calling Meteor.logout() on the client when this variable is true? With my scarce testing, it seems more stable. Could it be any kind of security hole?

Comment: It depends what you want exactly. It is secure if you design it so, since the code can only run on the server you can add preconditions to it. I'm not sure how it would be more secure with the profile.forceLogout or more stable. The best would be to group the users somehow into admins and non admins and use the selector of `Meteor.users.update` to determine whom and whom not to log out

Comment: I want to be able to log out users from an admin page. When removing the login-tokens, it seems like the user sometimes loses the connection, and thus the client does not know it has been logged out. (The server has removed the token, and the client will never know that it has been logged out, because it does not get any more updates from the server) When setting forceLogOut to true, and then based on that run Meteor.logout() on the client, it works all the time, because the client is still "connected", if that makes sense. (At least this is what it seems like for now.I will test more)

Comment: This may be the case when the user has been disconnected, but as soon as it reconnects the login is re-attempted with the loginToken (can see it in the websocket wire/frame) and as soon as it fails the user is logged out. You can experiment with this by running `Meteor.user()` after the reconnection. You would have to attune your app to make sure it pays attention to this reactively to ensure it has logged out, you wouldn't have to call `.logOut` as everything becomes invalidated the moment it realizes its logged out

Comment: Try to avoid using the forceLogOut because it would be going out of the way to get it to work when it would fluidly work without it if you can get it right

Comment: I can not see that it works the way you are proposing. The connection seems to completely die when removing loginTokens, and as such the reactiveness does not work. Please see my code examples that I added.

Comment: Note this is now:
db.users.update({}, {$set : { "services.resume.loginTokens" : [] }}, {multi:true});

Comment: In meteor 1.8 I had to clear both `"resume.loginTokens"` and `"services.resume.loginTokens"`

Answer (score 3):

Log out everyone but **not the current user (you)**:

```
Meteor.users.update({
    _id: {
        $ne: Meteor.user()._id
    }
}, {
    $set: {
        "services.resume.loginTokens": []
    }
}, {
    multi: true
});
```

Comment: In meteor 1.8 I had to clear both `"resume.loginTokens"` and `"services.resume.loginTokens"`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue recently - after deleting resume token of currently logged in user, Tracker.autorun wasn't able to (and it should be in such a case) detect changes in Meteor.userId() as in the following code:

```
Tracker.autorun(() => {
  console.log('currrent user', Meteor.userId());
});
```

It turned out that the problem was caused by one of the publications which logged in user subscribed. Somewhere in the routing-related code (I was using Iron router), I had:

```
export const AppController = RouteController.extend({
  waitOn() {
    if (!Meteor.userId()) {
      return Router.go('signIn');
    }
    Meteor.subscribe('data'),
  },
});
```

And the publication code was:

```
Meteor.publish('data', function () {
  if (!this.userId) {
    return; // this line caused the logout bug
  }
  return MyCollection.find();
}
```

The bug was caused by returning undefined (instead of an empty array) when `this.userId` was not set, which caused the publication to never be ready. For some strange reason, this also caused Tracker not to fire when resume token was deleted.

So the fix was:

```
Meteor.publish('data', function () {
  if (!this.userId) {
    return []; // this is the correct way to return empty set
  }
  return MyCollection.find();
}
```

Comment: oh wow! we had the same thing in a quite huge meteor project where we now wanted a better ux on server side logouts and were wondering why `Meteor.user()` wasn't picking up the change at all (sure there are workaround but they are ugly). Thanks so much for your detailed answer!